# RTP video stream: is presence of SDP file mandatory?

Tags: video-streaming, rtp

I have implemented a raw rtp stream. I want to play it using VLC or Mplayer. But it seems that video players cannot play this stream.

For example MPlayer says:

```
Stream not seekable!
Stray packet (seq[6]=1013 seq=987, newseq=-26 found at 12)
```

I dont get any idea what I have to do, to make video readable by this videoplayers. 
Should I add SDP ? Or theese players can play raw rtp stream ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDP is not required as long as receiver is aware of format of the streams. Stream not seekable means packets are not arriving at receiver sequentially as expected. Try with increase buffering time of players.

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
So this means that i'm setting wrond sequence number to RTP header?

Comment: Not necessarily, Packets arriving at receiver are out of sync. You can verify it using wireshark. Verify three fields. Seq no., Timestamp and marker bit.

Comment: "as long as receiver is aware of format of the streams". Well, strictly this is exact, but isn't SDP precisely the standard way to tell VLC or mplayer the "format of the streams"? To me it feels like saying "no you don't need documentation to use tool X, if you already know how to use it".

Answer (score 1):

Add a jitter buffer to handle reordering out-of-order packets to the receiver.  Note that if the data is far enough out-of-order (especially if it's late), you'll need to discard it instead of forwarding to the decoder.  The decoder should handle lost packets.